# RPi unreachable over network after bed leveling

Tags: octoprint, raspberry-pi, linux

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running a complete instance of the RPi OS with few extras, although I usually boot to the terminal and not to the desktop. Primarily, my RPi is dedicated to running Octoprint for my 3D printer (a Creality CR-10 V3), which has worked great for a long time. With 8 GB of RAM and a 128 GB micro SD card, it's not like my device is constrained on resources, so I am unsure why the Octoprint server intermittently becomes unavailable.

Before anybody suggests it, as though I did something wrong, I should mention first that the Octopi image never worked well for me. I fought many noble battles against its mighty dragons before deciding I should ditch it. Therefore, I installed a standard RPi OS image and manually followed the steps to set up Octoprint. That was necessary because absolutely nothing I tried would prevent the WiFi connection from cutting in and out. I also have a solid power supply, so that's not the culprit either.

What makes this issue different than the WiFi issue I previously experienced is that my network connection on the RPi remains stable. Moreover, despite being unreachable (except locally), the Octoprint server has not gone down. I can also not connect via SSH, and the RPi no longer responds to pings. I verified this by attaching peripherals and loading the desktop. After becoming unreachable to my laptop, I confirmed that `localhost:5000` remains available on the RPi, and there is an internet connection, so what gives? The server is up and running just fine.

Whenever this happens, if I am using Windows Remote Desktop, the connection there also goes down.

It seems like a firewall is blocking the connection, but that makes no sense. My anti-virus is not blocking it, and I don't see any firewalls in my RPi. To no avail, I already tried disabling the firewalls on my computer. The only thing that re-establishes connectivity, it seems, is restarting the RPi. But occasionally, it comes back on its own if I wait a long time.

There is a pattern here, though. The server/RPi becomes unreachable anytime I perform bed leveling. With some luck, connectivity sometimes comes back after finishing, but most of the time, it does not.

Version information:

- Linux Raspberry Pi 5.15.76-v8+ (x64)
- OctoPrint 1.8.6